# Getting 2 unique values from array

Tags: javascript

I have the following task - form array of values I need to pick 2 values which are not equal. I want to make it with if / loop logic to understand the basis. I've succeed with my task but my loop seems to me doesn't over and the page after several refresh crash down.

We'll be very appreciate for help with my code.

```js
var arrP = [];
var randomPersons = 2;
var nsm = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5"];
function randomGen() {
  for (i=0; i<randomPersons; i++) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nsm.length));
    arrP.push(rnd);
  }
}

do {
  randomGen();
}

    while (arrP[0] === arrP[1]);

document.write(nsm[arrP[0]] + "<br>" + nsm[arrP[1]]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `==="undefined"` doesn't check if a value is `undefined`, it checks that it's the string `"undefined"`. You would need to use `typeof` to check for the actual undefined type ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof))

Comment: DBS you are right, thanks. Corrected by the same result.

Comment: Lain, to check if 2 values in my new array are equal.

Comment: 1) Why would any of those be undefined tho? The statement executes before the condition. Any time you call `randomGen` you keep pushing to `arrP`.  2) The initial `arrP[0]` and `arrP[1]` do not change, which leads to a never ending `while` in the case of `arrP[0] === arrP[1]`.

Comment: Javascript, agreed, but while (arrP[0] === arrP[1]); gives me the same luck - script crashed.

Comment: Exactly, because the numbers `arrP[0]` and `arrP[1]` never change. You are creating `arrP[2]`and `arrP[3]` instead using `push`. Put `arrP = [];` inside your function before the `for` and you should be good or change the inside of the `for` to `arrP[i] = rnd;`

Comment: Javascript thanks for explanation and the solution - please post your comment as an answer and it will be accepted.

Comment: This is more of a typo question. I recommend deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

A rather naive implementation might be something like this. (Something more optimized would not need to modify the input array, for instance.)

It assumes that the `arr` is a "bag" of choices and doesn't really look at equality at all. In other words, if your "bag" is `["John", "John", "Peasoup", "Booze", "Scaffold"]`, it's possible to get two Johns in the output.

```js
function pickRandom(arr, num) {
  const output = [];
  const input = [...arr]; // shallow-copy so we can modify it
  // work to do and choices to pick?
  while(input.length > 0 && output.length < num) {
    // Pick random remaining index...
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * input.length);
    const [pick] = input.splice(index, 1); // Remove from input
    output.push(pick); // ... put into output
  }
  return output;
}

var picks = pickRandom(["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5"], 2);
document.getElementById("x").value = JSON.stringify(picks, null, 2);
```

```html
<textarea id="x" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```